# SQL SELECT Percentage of Rows Based on Column Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to return 15% of rows based on column values.  For example, I have a citizenship column and gender column as well as name email,etc.  I want to return 15% of each scenario in those columns.  If citizenship = USA I would want 15% of total rows with USA and male another 15% of USA and female and another of 15% of USA and unknown. The same would go for each other citizenship in my result (ie Chinese, Canadian, etc.)

I am able to get 15% of all rows, but not based on column values.

A very stripped down query looks something like this.

```
SELECT TOP 15 PERCENT FROM (
SELECT name
    , email
    , citizenship
    , gender
FROM bio) a
```

Comment: `TOP` returns the "top" rows from the **entire** dataset, not per individual group. You always have no `ORDER BY` so what, in your data, defines the "top" and what defines the "bottom" in your data?

Answer (score 1):

You want a stratified sample.  You can do this using:

```
select top 15 percent b.*
from bio b
order by row_number() over (partition by citizenship, gender order by (select null));
```

Comment: Do you mean `partition` in addition to `order`?  I think this will be disproportionately skewed towards whichever citizenship/gender is alphabetically highest, rather than returning a sampling from all citizenship/gender combinations.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. It returns 15% of rows based on citizenship, but does not take into account gender.  So my results was only USA Males with no Females. If I had 100 USA Males and 50 USA Females I would want to return 15 USA Males and 8 USA Females. Thanks.

Comment: @APH . . . In fact, I did.  I changed the answer.  Thank you.